# Bundle Identifier and Provisioning Profile

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, xcode

Is there any relation between the Bundle Identifier we see in Info.plist and the Provisioning Profile under Organizer (like some para should be same)?

Also should the same value be also the same in Info/Settings?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When you create an App ID you need to fill a name(ex: 'YourCompany') for it and a wildcard bundle identifier(something like ‘`com.yourcompany.*`’). The ‘`.*`’ at the end is the wildcard, needed so that you only need one set of provisioning profiles for all your applications.

A provisioning profile needs an AppID in order to be created.

in the Info.plist of your application in the BundleIdentifier you can put com.yourcompany.TestApp and your application will work on your device.

com.yourcompany.TestApp should be in the info.plist and in the info>properties>identifier.

[here](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/iphone-sdk-install-apps-on-iphone-devices-for-development/) you can find a tutorial that describes what it needs to be done in order to create AppIDs and provisioning profiles. If you'll read it you will understand how they work and what is the relationship between them.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the info. I just used one of the App IDs from my dev account and entered the same in Info.plist and Identifier. 

However when I Build for iphonedistribution, I get an error
Code Sign error: Provisioning profile 'CXXXXXXX-7210-401D-A0F2-1586B5AXX28' can't be found

Comment: you should also read http://developer.apple.com/iphone/manage/distribution/index.action  section of the Apple Developer Connection iPhone site. This explains step-by-step what you will need to do, in the correct order.

Comment: Thanks for the info...I am following the instructions given on the site...But seem to be doing something wrong at the step;
"Create and download your iOS Distribution Provisioning Profile for App Store Distribution"

Comment: My question is When I drag the .mobileprovision onto Xcode in the dock to install, should it show me green icon (and not "This profile cannot be installed on the device") ? Is that correct? I am getting "cannot be installed on device"

Comment: That is the reason I am not sure what I am doing wrong. My guess is in when I do "Create iOS Distribution Provisioning Profile"
the App Id that I select, there are multiple options (some for previous app)...I do not know what to select there ? 
Please help me..I am totally confused..

Comment: do you want to publish your app to the store or install it on the device?

Comment: I want to publish to the app store. (To verify the distribution profile, should it also work on the device..i mean just to verify the settings)

Comment: I hope I am clear and not confusing you with what I am looking for

Comment: Distribution certificates are only for submitting applications to Apple for review. The error message you received, "This profile cannot be installed on the device", is correct.

Comment: here are two movies that will guide you through the whole distribution process: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OtlH4wGbWp0 and http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AQ9PAghP-qg

Answer (score 2):

the simplest way to find bundle identifier from provisioning profile is 
open it in text editor and search for string "com." the first result will be your bundle identifier.

please do not change or save file after that otherwise you will find it dumb file.

Thanks