# Provisioning profile issue, I just can't run my application on device

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ios-simulator, provisioning-profile

I'm getting this message when I try to run on my device:

> A valid provisioning profile matching the application's Identifier 'my app bundle ' could not be found

I am able to run the app on iPhone Simulator without problem.

I was able to connect to the device before, I don't know what is going on...

I already deleted everything and tried again, even with a new App ID created on the portal but it didn't work either.

I just don't know what to do to run the app on my device?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> A valid provisioning profile matching the application's **Identifier 'my app bundle '** could not be found

Please ensure that the identifer is consistent with the App ID you created for the provisioning profiles on developer portal.

For example, if you created App ID **"A1B2C3D4E5.com.yourdomain.*"** and assigned it to your provisioning profile, your app must have a bundle identifer like **"com.yourdomain.someapp"** so that it can be correctly signed.

Also I don't think space character is allowed in the identifier. See [Information Property List Key Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001431-102070):

> The bundle ID string must be a uniform type identifier (UTI) that contains only alphanumeric (A-Z,a-z,0-9), hyphen (-), and period (.) characters.

You may refer to:

- ["Creating and Configuring App IDs"](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/DevPortalGuide/CreatingandConfiguringAppIDs/CreatingandConfiguringAppIDs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011159-CH18-SW1) in iOS Team Administration Guide.
- [Bundle Identifier and Provisioning Profile](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5313537/1241690)

Answer (score 0):

Running an app on simulator doesn't require code signing and hence no provisioning profile. As it was working earlier and you've tried deleting and reinstalling everything, see whether your code signing certificate has been revoked or expired.